# Translation of Heisenberg's papers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resonance, specific-reference

Is there any English translation for he following Heisenberg's paper?

> "Mehrkörperproblem und Resonanz in der Quantenmechanik", Zeitschrift für Physik, Volume 38, Issue 6-7, pp. 411-426. Publication Date: 06/1926.

Answer (score 1):

The translation can be found [here](http://nonloco-physics.0catch.com/multi.pdf). I found it in [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6659/english-translation-of-heisenbergs-papers) StackExchange question.

Comment: It's not an answer it will better suit as a helpful comment.